# Using React Material-UI & Formik, TextField type date does not update after assign data from server

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, formik

I have the following form, which is working fine when a new date is selected and find on form submit. But when I get the form value from the server and assign the form value for edit, then the date field does not shows any value.

```
<Formik
          initialValues={
            props.acdAcademicSession !== undefined &&
            props.acdAcademicSession.academicSessionId !== undefined
              ? {
                  ...props.acdAcademicSession,
                }
              : { ...state }
          }
          enableReinitialize={true}
          onSubmit={onSubmitForm}
          validationSchema={schema}
        >
          {({
            values,
            errors,
            touched,
            handleChange,
            handleBlur,
            handleSubmit,
            isSubmitting,
          }) => (
            <form
              noValidate={true}
              autoComplete="off"
              onSubmit={handleSubmit}
              className={`${formClasses.root}`}
            >                  
              <div className="row">
                <div className="col-6">
                  <TextField
                    type="Date"
                    label="Starting Month"
                    fullWidth
                    margin="normal"
                    variant="outlined"
                    size="small"
                    name="startDate"
                    onBlur={handleBlur}
                    onChange={handleChange}                    
                    value={values.startDate}
                    InputLabelProps={{
                      shrink: true,
                    }}
                    helperText={touched.startDate && errors.startDate}
                    error={Boolean(touched.startDate && errors.startDate)}
                  />
                </div>

              </div>

              form>
          )}
        </Formik>
```

Comment: Are you able to remove all the non-relevant data and keep a minimal working example?

Answer (score 1):

Hope below helps:

1. Set the enableReinitialize to true on Formik component;
2. Set an initial state for the initialValues variable (useState for who is working with hooks);
3. Update the initialValues to the new one inside your side
   effect (useEffect for who is working with hooks or componentDidMount
   / componentDidUpdate).

Source: See [here and read more](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik/issues/811#issuecomment-586446649)